# c++ class-to-class data transfer

Tags: c++, class, interaction

I am working in c++, i want to input from text file then transfer to the variables in the class. I have 2 classes: `class A` and `class B` which are present by:

```
class A
{
   public:
   double i;
   double r;

   double function(double s)
   {
      i = s*s+r;
      return i;
   };

class B: public A 
{
  public:
     A A;
     int c;
     double e;
     e = A.r;
     c = A.function(c);
     double h;
     h=e+c;
};

int main()
{
   ifstream data;

   double f[3];

   data.open("A.txt", ios::in);

   for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
   {
     data>> f[i];
   }
   A A;
   A.r = f[0];
};
```

the `r` that I input in `class A` didn't remain values when I use it in `class B`. I don't know how to deal with this problem. please help me!! thank you co much!!!

Comment: Please use indentation. More people are likely to read/understand your code if you do.

Comment: I don't understand what *"didn't remain values"* means - please provide sample input and output (both expected and actually received) (a.k.a..: provide a [mcve])

Comment: Your code won't ever compile. `.` cannot be used to access into a type, and statements can't be inserted inside a class body.

Comment: You need to read on what is a class, declaration and instance, and how inheritance and composition works. People are often mixing those and it's fine when they know what they are talking about, but when you learn it it's best to do so in a fine detailed way.

Comment: Thank you guys for comment. I simply wanna use the result of class A inside class B so could you please tell me the easiest way to do that cause c++ a little complicate to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by the fact that your class B contains two instances of class A: first is inhered public A and the second is a field A A; So every instance of class B will have b.r field and b.A.r field. This is allowed by language, but in this case you probably need only one of them.